# Unable To Open DocuSign Embedded Singing URL in InCognito mode of browser

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to open embedded url in chrome's incognito mode, but it does not load in incognito mode.

I am using REST APIs to generate this URL

I am attaching screenshot for the reference

[image]

Comment: I just tried and it worked just fine in incognito. Does it work if you use regular chrome?

Comment: It works in regular chrome, as I am developer, it works perfectly in my machine even in incognito mode. But when I host APIs, and another developer tries it , it does not work. It shows Login issue as mentioned in the attaches screenshot. Screenshot has been taken from front-end developer's screen

Comment: oh, you didn't explain this, this is expected if you have two developers

Comment: What do you mean "this is expected if you have two developers" that scenario was for my local machine where I am writing code.Code sits in my machine that is why it works for me with lcoal host, but not on hosted server, or when APIs are deployed on server and I generate URL and try it to paste in incognito mode it does not even work for me, it seems like in cognito requires some different access or auth token is not working , it shows login failure it means auth token is not passing if in cognito mode is used

Comment: Well, now I'm confused, you wrote "It works in regular chrome, as I am developer, it works perfectly in my machine even in incognito mode."

Comment: Does it work in Incognito mode or not?

Comment: If the issue is that it's not working on server, it can be that the server is locked-down and you cannot store cookies on the server's browser which is why it's not working on the server

Comment: So What is the solution then?, because for my previous client too it was not working. So either I am doing something wrong or it is an issue with DocuSign side

Comment: You have to use regular browser, not incognito mode

Comment: Browser must allow saving of cookies to client. That is required for this to work

Comment: Hi Inbar, Do you have this somewhere mentioned in DocuSign documentations/limitations or where users have asked this same question or problem as I have, I need to show the proof to client, it is not doable in incognito

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/privacy/cookie-policy/

Comment: Notice that this is about cookies, the problem is your browser cannot store these cookies in the configuration that it is in

Comment: Inbar this is not about browser, tell me when I am calling APIs and generating Embedded URLs, where this Cookie comes into picture, all is API based. Even I see this code in C# SDKs Examples, and I am also using it, but it is also not helping in incognito mode:           services.ConfigureNonBreakingSameSiteCookies();
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            });

Comment: You are saying you get an error message from the API? what API and what error message?

Comment: Lol, leave it man (where did I mention about error in my last statement, I asked, you guys have SameSiteCookie class in C# SDK code , and I am using it , still it does not allow me to access embedded signing in incognito mode), it is very hard to explain even with the clear statements

Comment: I would recommend working with DocuSign customer support, because yes, it is hard to understand what you mean and they can set up a call with you